# Java HtmlUnit form.getInputByValue("Login Now!").click();

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to make a application which would connect to a site with the login provided by the user. I don't have any experience in interacting with websites in Java so I googled some and found hmtlunit to fit my needs.

But I ran into an error when trying to click the submit button for the login form:

```
public static boolean attempt_login(String username, String password) throws ElementNotFoundException, IOException {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
            public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("handleRefresh");
            }
        });

        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(Config.LOGIN_PAGE);
        List<HtmlForm> forms = page.getForms();
        HtmlForm form = null;
        for(HtmlForm f : forms){
            if(f.getId().equals("login_form")){
                form = f;
            }
        }
        if(form == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Could not find form!");
        }
        form.getInputByName("username").setValueAttribute(username);
        form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute(password);

        page = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Login Now!").click();

        System.out.println(page.asText());
        return false;}
```

Somehow it fails to find the submitButton to login

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[value] attributeValue=[Login Now!]
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.getInputByValue(HtmlForm.java:737)
at domain.Helper.attempt_login(Helper.java:41)
at TesterStartUp.main(TesterStartUp.java:15)
```

The html source code:

```
<button type="submit" value="Login Now!" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundPosition='bottom';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundPosition='top';" onclick="return SetFocus();">Login Now!</button>
```

When I googled for a solution, I found something about disabling javascript would help. So i told the webclient to disabled it ( webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);) but still had the exception.

At first I had the same issue with trying to select the form ("login_form") but there was a method where I could get the list of all forms and then just see if one matched the list. I couldn't find a way around it for the submit button, So I hoped someone else knows a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Sir Troll

Answer (score 1):

The HtmlUnit [`getInputByValue()` method](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlForm.html#getInputByName%28java.lang.String%29) operating on a `<form>` will only return types of [HtmlInput](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/Htmlnput.html), and the only Input Button type -- [HtmlButtonInput](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlButtonInput.html) -- represents `<input type="button">` and NOT `<button>`. You will need to change your HTML or use a different HtmlUnit method call.

Comment: It isn't my webspage, so I can't change the html. Which method should I use? since the only 'unique' item in the submit button is the value

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of issue that I resolved myself:

When you try to login using html unit first check if login box is appearing onclick using jquery or not. If login box/div is appearing after click a button then you need to refresh the page (web client) to access new input elements

```
 HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.yourwebsite.com/#");
 HtmlAnchor link=page.getElementByName("link");
 link.click();
 page.refresh();
```

If your site has a button instead of anchor link change it for html button, After refreshing may you can found the element.

*Hope it will help and solve your issue*